# How to redirect Magento after some operation to an url passed in query string? Possible?

Tags: magento, redirect, shopping-cart, product

This Wiki article: [Adding a Product to the Cart via Querystring](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/catalog/adding_a_product_to_the_cart_via_querystring) describes how one can put product with specific id to the cart directly from querystring. So for simple product it would be something like this:

```
/path/to/app/checkout/cart/add?product=[id]&qty=[qty]
```

But after it adds a product, Magento redirects browser to the home page and shows nice message that product has been added successfully. But we need to show a Shopping Cart directly, not a home page. So maybe it is possible to add another param to the querystring to achieve this?

I know I could write a module, but I just stumbled upon this possibility, so might be there is a way to easily redirect as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a few things you could try before going the custom code route.

In the Admin UI you could make sure the redirect flag is correct.

```
URL: /admin/system_config/edit/section/checkout
Fieldset: Shopping Cart
Field: After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart
```

If that doesn't solve the problem, try this one.

```
/checkout/cart/add?product=[id]&qty=[qty]&in_cart=true
```

Comment: Last line worked great! Thanks. Is there a way to not show add confirmation message? Maybe another argument, like - &notify=false?..

Comment: Well there are a few things that look promising, but just look over Mage_Checkout_CartController and you should have a clue what to start playing with.